# Is it legal to have a function pointer template parameter accept an rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, function-pointers, rvalue-reference

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, I try to compile the following:

```
template <void (*f)(int && y)>
void foo() {}
```

and get this error:

```
error C2993: 'int &&' : illegal type for non-type template parameter 'y'
```

Is that really illegal? Or is this a bug in MSVS? If so, does anyone know if it works in a later version?

Comment: Nothing illegal here. It could be that MSVC is confused by the name `y` for first parameter of the function pointer type, which isn't necessary here. Try `template <void (*f)(int&&)>`.

Comment: For G++ you have to add -std=c++0x as a compiler option or it won't parse.

Comment: jrok, you're brilliant! Dropping the "y" works around the bug. If you post this as an official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: GCC in C++11 mode accepts this as well, so it is likely a MSVC bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a rejects-valid bug in VS2012's compiler, which is getting confused by the parameter name in the function type into thinking that the function type's parameter is a template parameter, hence the complaint.  G++ 4.8 and 4.9 in C++11 mode accept this code, and so do Clang 3.3 and ICC 13; this was checked using [Godbolt's interactive compiler](http://gcc.godbolt.org).  Also, as per [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 14.1 (temp.param) p4, pointers and lvalue references to functions are allowed without restriction on the function parameter or return types:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally 
>   *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

The workaround is as jrok mentioned in the comments: simply remove the parameter name from the function type -- all compilers I was able to test with accept this.